# Is the image of an analytic function $f(D)$ connecte?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let   $f : D  \rightarrow  \mathbb{C}$  be an analytic  function, where $D$ is an open subset  of $ \mathbb{C}$.
>   If $f(D)$ is  closed  in $\mathbb{C}$ then is $f(D)$ connected?

I think  yes  take  constant  function.

Comment: If $f$ is the constant function, sure, then $f(D)$ is connected no matter what $D$ is (as long as it's non-empty). But we don't know that $f$ is constant, just that it's analytic.

Comment: You say a statement is true by giving a proof.. you say a statement is false by giving a counter example... You do not prove something by giving an example...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik That's a gross simplification. Some statements are proven with examples and disproven with proofs. In fact, all statements that are proven with a proof and disproven with a counterexample have a corresponding converse statement that is proven with an example and disproven with a proof.

Comment: Do you care to give some examples supporting your statement? @Arthur

Comment: give  me  counter examp-le  @PraphullaKoushik im  confsued

Comment: See the answer below :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Statements of the form "there exists $x$ such that $P(x)$" can be proved by simply providing an example of an $x$ such that $P(x)$. Its negation, "there is no $x$ such that $P(x)$," requires a proof, not just an example. Notice this last statement is equivalent to "for all $x$, $P(x)$", which is a statement that is proven with a proof or disproven with a counterexample.

Comment: @kccu Does that first example fit in the above scenario?

Comment: It is relevant because you claimed that "You say a statement is true by giving a proof.. you say a statement is false by giving a counter example... You do not prove something by giving an example..." which is absolutely not true in general.

Comment: The situation of "for all $x$, $P(x)$" is what is asked in the question and as you said, and as what I said,  the statement is proven with a  proof or disproven with a counterexample.. @kccu

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Sure, here is an example supporting my statement: Fermat's last theorem says "There is no integer solution to $a^n + b^n = c^n$ for any integer $n\geq 3$". This is proven with a proof, or disproven with a counterexample. The converse "There is an integer solution to $a^n + b^n = c^n$ for some integer $n\geq 3$" is proven with an example and disproven with a proof. The list of statements you can do this to is pretty long.

Comment: @kccu My comment was specific to this kind of questions, not a general comment..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I agree, in this instance the statement cannot be proved by example. But it is misleading to tell someone that an example can never be used to prove a statement. It is more instructive and helpful to explain *why* a single example does not prove a statement of the form in the question.

Comment: @kccu I could not realise that some thing I say in some situation could be taken as a general advice.. I repeat, this is not a general advice... No single pill for all situations... I appreciate your comments, time :) Thank you :)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik "You say a statement is true by giving a proof.. you say a statement is false by giving a counter example... You do not prove something by giving an example..." sounds **a lot** like general advice. It might be a language barrier that makes it sound that way, but that's still how I and kccu read it. And as general advice it's simply not true. In this specific situation, it turns out to be true.

Comment: @Arthur As I have clarified now, any further discussion on this is not useful (not in general, I mean for me).. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in general that's wrong! take for $D$ disjunct union of $B_i:=\{z \in \mathbb{C} \vert \vert z-i \vert < 1/2 \} $ and $B_{-i}:= \{z \in \mathbb{C} \vert \vert z+i \vert < 1/2 \}$; ie $D:= B_{i} \cup B_{-i}$. The finction $f: D \to \mathbb{C}$ that maps $B_{i}$ to $1$ and $B_{-i}$ to $-1$ is analytic since it's a local property and closed but the image is not connected

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be false.

Take D to be the union of two disjoint (open) balls $B_1, B_2$ centred at, respectively, $z_1, z_2 \in \Bbb{C}$. Define $f(B_1) :=   \{z_1\}, \; f(B_2) := \{z_2\}$, then $f$ is clearly analytic but its image is closed and not connected.